# Loop after specified delay in for loop

Tags: javascript, delay

I have this but that doesn't seem to work

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // My code
  }, 1000);
}
```

It works one time but then it will not work

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Does `setInterval` not work for you?

Comment: I think you want to execute some code after let's say `1000` milliseconds. Use `setInterval`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setTimeout in for-loop does not print consecutive values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `1000` as your duration, it makes your code to look like it's only working for the first `i` instance. What happens here is, `for` loop executes quickly but each `setTimeout` for each `i` will almost be executed at the same time, but not exactly... there'll be split `ms` between each `i`.

let's say the loop executes within about `300ms` with each `i` executed at `300ms` / 5... this means each `setTimeout` will be just `300/5 ms` behind the next one. So when this is executed, it will seem like the first `i` is the one that shows the desired result and the others don't.

However, based on what I think you're trying to achieve, you should instead try to create a Timeout delay of about `1000ms` between each `i`. So you should do it this way:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  (function(i){
    setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
    }, i*1000);
  })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should multiply your time by i.
If you only put your time, all the iterations will execute at the same time after 1000 ms.

So the code will be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // My code
  }, 1000*i);
}
```

Comment: This won't work if `i` is declared with keyword `var`, it should be declared using `let`

Comment: @matrixersp good point. It's worth noting that it will still work but it will just keep outputting the last value of `i`, which will be 5 in this case.

Comment: @MosiaThabo This solution works perfectly unless `// My code` should use variable `i`. Although in this case the `setInterval` solution is better, because it creates only one timer, while the `setTimeout` solution creates a new timer and anonymous function for each iteration. In addition, the `setInterval` solution allows you easily to interrupt the process whenever you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) is better for this case:

```js
let i = 0;
const interval = setInterval(function() {
    if(i == 4) clearInterval(interval);
    // My code
    console.log(i);
    i++;
}, 1000);
```