# javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'X' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror

Im wondering why this function is returning this error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: capasPlay is not defined
at funPlay.handleFunPlay

```
funPlay.prototype.handleFunPlay = function handleFunPlay() {
        
        capasPlay = [capa4_48R, capa4_49R, capa4_50R, capa4_51R, capa4_52R, capa4_53R, capa4_54R, capa4_55R, capa4_56R];

        
        var index;
        
        for (index=0; index <= capasPlay.leght; index++){
            
            window.setTimeout(function(){capasPlay[index].setVisible(false)}, 1000);
        }
    };
    return funPlay;
```

The array is made from variables like this:

```
var capa4_48R = new TileLayer({
                source: new TileWMS({
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
                    params: { 'LAYERS': 'earth:4_48R', 'TILED': true },
                    serverType: 'geoserver',
                })
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nowhere in the code you've posted tries to read a property called `X`. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem you're having. At very least the error _might_ come from `setVisible` method, so perhaps show us that,

Comment: sorry man. You are right. The error is: Uncaught ReferenceError: capasPlay is not defined at funPlay.handleFunPlay

Comment: error is pretty clear, where are you defining capasPlay?

Comment: Here is the definition of the array:

Comment: capasPlay = [capa4_48R, capa4_49R, capa4_50R, capa4_51R, capa4_52R, capa4_53R, capa4_54R, capa4_55R, capa4_56R];

Answer (score 1):

> If you are not using vanilla Javascript, you need to explicitly define
> variables with a `var`, `const` or `let`.

```
const capasPlay = [ ... ]
```

Comment: I have defining it as a const but the same error happening. Maybe the "setTimeout" function is not working with the iteration. Maybe it wasnt thought to work like that. Not sure. Thank you friend

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you replaced whatever property you're actually calling with "X"?

I see an issue with your loop which would cause an undefined property error. `index` will be out of range when the function triggered by `setTimeout` is called. To fix this, you need to save a copy of the current index for each iteration of the loop.

```js
for (index=0; index <= capasPlay.leght; index++){
    const i = index;
    window.setTimeout(function(){capasPlay[i].setVisible(false)}, 1000);
}
```

**Update**

As suggested in [setTimeout in for-loop does not print consecutive values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values), there is a better solution that I was not aware of.

```js
for (let index=0; index <= capasPlay.leght; index++){
    window.setTimeout(function(){capasPlay[index].setVisible(false)}, 1000);
}
```