# JS function for loop not waiting for timeout

Tags: javascript

**Problem**

My for loop in JS is just passing all of the elements without waiting for timeout, I tried few things like checking [setTimeout in for-loop does not print consecutive values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values) this topic but couldn't find any solution.

**What I Want**

I want my for loop to wait for timeout for every element in array.

**Code**

```
function generateList(level) {
    //her levelda olusacak parca sayisi 1 artar
    generatedList = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < level; x++) {
        //her blok arasına timeout koymak istiyorum
        generateNext();
        setTimeout(function() {}, 400);
        //timeout doesn't work between elements
    }
}

function generateNext() {
    // bu kısım sonraki seviye için tek bir parça hazırlar
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    var name = constList[random - 1];
    $("#" + name).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
    playSound(name);
    generatedList.push(random);
}
```

I want to call generateNext() function after 400 ms but here, my code calls all of them at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the problem is that, `setTimeout` is asynchronous, it cannot delay the synchronous execution until unless either pushed to stay synchronous .

For this usage you want to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

```
function generateList(level) {
    //her levelda olusacak parca sayisi 1 artar
    generatedList = [];
    let counter = 0
    const interval = setInterval(generateNext, 400)
}



function generateNext() {
    // bu kısım sonraki seviye için tek bir parça hazırlar
    if (counter === level) {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    var name = constList[random - 1];
    $("#" + name).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
    playSound(name);
    generatedList.push(random);
    counter++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `generateNext()` inside the timeout function

```
setTimeout(function() {
   generateNext()
}, 400);
```

Comment: unfortunately not working