# setTimeout not working inside of my for loop - skipping it completely

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

```js
function whatever () {
  for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     do something
    slowDown();
  };
};

 function slowDown () {
   time = setTimeout(function (){
       do something else
   }, 5000);
};
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: `slowDown()` will schedule something to execute *later*. It will not actually slow down anything. If you have a loop over 10 items, then you'd just have 10 tasks scheduled to execute 5 seconds later.

Comment: If I try it the other way around, the length of the array is undefined

Comment: You can await a promise instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than that, why not just set and interval, execute on the current array value until it's done, then clear it?

```
let ctr = 0, time = setInterval(function() {
    let curitem = arr[ctr];
    // do somethign with curitem
    if (++ctr >= arr.length) clearInterval(time)
  }, 5000);
```

Comment: thank you. this works well. however, when the ctr++ >= arr.length I'm getting undefined

Answer (score -1):

What @vlaz has pointed out in the comment to the question is correct:

> slowDown() will schedule something to execute later. It will not actually slow down anything. If you have a loop over 10 items, then you'd just have 10 tasks scheduled to execute 5 seconds later.

Not sure if this might help, but I think this is quite similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/5226333/10293708