# How to add eventListener function to elements with unique id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I have some dynamic cards:

[image]

and I want to add eventListener to all play buttons (their code is):

```
<a href="link">
    <img src="play.svg">
    <audio src="myMusic.mp3"></audio>
</a>
```

When I click to "play", it should look like below:

[image]

(it should change image and should also play audio)

My JS code so far done is:

```
<script>
var imgsPlay = document.getElementsByClassName('play-img-loop');
var audioPlayers = document.getElementsByClassName('audio-player');

window.onload = function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < imgsPlay.length; i++) {
            imgsPlay[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {

                if(this.getAttribute('src') == "img/icons/play.svg") {
                    this.setAttribute('src', "img/icons/play_red.svg");
                    audioPlayers[i].play();

                } else if(this.getAttribute('src') == "img/icons/play_red.svg") {
                    this.setAttribute('src', "img/icons/play.svg");
                    audioPlayers[i].pause();
                }
                
            });
        }    
    }

</script>
```

(I can do it manually, but) can not dynamically. How can I do this ?

Comment: Please add your javascript code that you tried and show your efforts in this, [I downvoted](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Can you please post the javascript code which you have done for dynamic addition of dom

Comment: Also don't add event handlers to several things. Instead delegate from the nearest static container

Comment: This is not hard at all, you should at least try. SO is not a "Free development platform"

Comment: I have problem with passing argument to the inner function. The variable "i" is not shown in the inner function

Comment: Closure [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) - you can avoid this completely using delegation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the incorrect handling of closures. The event listener call back will never get the correct value of `i` by the way you have written it. The value of `i` will always be the last one when the events are fired.

The easiest workaround is to define the variable `i` only for the scope of a single iteration - which is what the `let` do.

```
    for(let i = 0; i < imgsPlay.length; i++) {
        imgsPlay[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {

            if(this.getAttribute('src') == "img/icons/play.svg") {
             ...
    }
```

Useful reference: [setTimeout in for-loop does not print consecutive values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values)

Comment: It is highly recommended to not even have that problem simply by delegating to a static container as I suggest in my answer

Comment: Thanks, it solved problem. "var" didn't work but "let work", could you explain why is it like this ?

Comment: [DUPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1):

You need to delegate! If not, then your question is just a dupe of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Here I assume you have a container called cardContainer

I am a little confused as to _red means playing or paused, so change the code below to match. Your example HTML does not match the code you show, there are no classes on the player and image, I therefor assume you do have those in the actual code

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.getElementById('cardContainer').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains('play-img-loop')) {
      const src = tgt.getAttribute('src');
      const running = src.includes('_red');
      const audioPlayer = tgt.closest('a').querySelector('audio');
      tgt.setAttribute('src', `img/icons/play$(running?'':'_red').svg`);
      if (running) audioPlayer.pause();
      else audioPlayer.play();
    }
  });
});
```