# How to correctly pass parameters through nested functions in for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I'm trying to use nodejs to run a loop functions `oh_lawd_it_chonky()` that is supposed to do the following: Loop `target_users` array passing each user to `initialize()` for authorization, for each given user get data using `returnbigdatachunk()` take that data and refine it or do something to it using `process_returnbigdatachunk()` push each of the results of that for each user to an array `output`.

I have each of the `initialize()`, `returnbigdatachunk()` and `process_returnbigdatachunk()` working individually and so I've omitted the details of those functions for the sake of simplicity in this post, I just can't seem to get the darn `oh_lawd_it_chonky()` function working. I don't quite understand how to pass through the user parameters correctly in nested functions like this. Please help if you can! Sorry this isn't quite a working example.

```
const target_users = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3'];

//authorize each user
function initialize(user) {
//do the stuff to get authorization
}

//loop through all the users and build an array of all the process_returnbigdatachunk
const oh_lawd_it_chonky = async () => {
for (var f = 0; f < target_users; f++) {
try {

  //get data of passed in user
  const returnbigdatachunk = async () => {
    const auth = initialize(user[target_users[f]]);

    let output = [];

    //refine data of passed in user
    const process_returnbigdatachunk = async () => {
        try {
          const data = await returnbigdatachunk();

          //push refined data into output array
          output.push(process_returnbigdatachunk)     
          console.log("crampus: " + output)
        } catch (e) {
          console.error('Failed to process returnbigdatachunk', e);
        }
      };
  };
} catch (e) {
  console.error('Failed to process returnbigdatachunk', e);
}
}
};
```

Comment: `const nameOfFunction = singleParam => {/* ... */}` or `const nameOfFunction = (param1, param2, { destructuring }, ...spread) => {/* ... */}`.

Comment: I'm trying to interpret the meaning of 'spread' and 'destructuring', and where these name0fFunction would go. Sorry I'm pretty new still.

Comment: Replace `nameOfFunction` with whatever you will, e.g. `oh_lawd_it_chonky`. You can ignore the spread and destructuring part (or google it).

Answer (score 0):

[setTimeout in for-loop does not print consecutive values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values)

`block-scoped`
change you `var f = 0` to `let f = 0`