# increase delay in SetTimeout after each loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Please help me with this problem. After each loop occurance, I wanted to log data with an increase in seconds.

**my result (logs data just after 1 second)**

```js
for(let i=1;i<=3;i++){
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i) // this logs after each second
  },i*1000)
}
```

**expected result :**

1. after 1 second - print - console.log(1)
2. after 2 second - print - console.log(2)
3. after 3 second - print - console.log(3)

Comment: Isn't your code currently doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to increase the delay between each log, you can compute the sum of arithmetic sequence.

```js
for(let i=1;i<=3;i++){
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i)
  },( i * (1+i) / 2) * 1000)
}
```

Or use an extra variable to accumulate the sum

```js
let acc = 0
for(let i=1;i<=3;i++){
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i)
  },(acc += i) * 1000)
}
```

Or even play with async await

```js
function delay(ms){
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    setTimeout(resolve,ms);
  });
}

(async ()=>{
  for(let i=1;i<=3;i++){
    await delay(i * 1000);
    console.log(i)
  }
})();
```

Comment: This works as expected, Thanks a lot for giving out in 3 different ways.