# JS question on setTimeout and block scope

Tags: javascript

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // debugger
  var log = function () {
    // debugger
    console.log(i)
  };
  var logWrappper = function () {
    console.log(i);
    log();
  }
  // logWrappper();
  setTimeout(logWrappper, 10)
}
```

I have code like above, if I invoke `logWrapper` directly,the `console.log(i)` outputs the same result(0-9) both in `log` and `logWrapper`, however if I pass it to a setTimeout and invoke it later, `console.log(i)` in logWrapper remains the same(0-9) while it outputs 10 times 9 in `log`, can anybody explain it? thank you very much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values

This will probably answer your question.

Comment: Because it just calls `log`, and there's only one `log` at call time, the last one that has been defined.

Comment: `i` uses `let` (scoped to the loop) so you get new `i` each loop. `log` uses `var` (scoped to the function) so `log` function gets overwritten each loop and the last `log` uses the `i` from the last loop.