# Display a message on the console with a delay

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I have this code:

```
function printDelay(j) {
  if (j != 0) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(j);
    }, 1000);
    j--;
    print(j);
  } else {
    console.log("END!");
  }
}

printDelay(5);
```

Why it doesn't print the numbers 5,4,3,2,1 with a delay of 1 second?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setTimeout in for-loop does not print consecutive values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values)

Comment: Because you set a delay to 1 second?

Comment: setTimeout is always executed immediately, only the callback of setTimeout is executed after the 1000 ms delay.

Answer (score 3):

You need to fix a typo where you call `print(j)` instead of `printDelay(j);` also you must move it (as well as the `j--` line) inside the callback of setTimeout.

```js
function printDelay(j) {
  if (j != 0) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(j);
      j--;
      printDelay(j);
    }, 1000);
   
  } else {
    console.log("END!");
  }
}

printDelay(5);
```