# setInterval not working (firing only once) in Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, setinterval

Just as the title says: `setInterval` is only firing its callback once.

manifest.json:

```
{
    //...
    "content_scripts" : [{
        "js" : ["code.js"],
        //...
    }],
    //...
}
```

code.js (example):

```
setInterval(alert('only shown once'),2000);
```

Why, and how I could fix it? The code works well outside of an extension (even in a bookmarklet).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
setInterval(function() { alert('only shown once') },2000);
```

You need to pass a function reference like `alert` and not a return value `alert()`

Comment: Oh, you're right. There is a problem elsewhere and my attempt at checking it with alert was sloppy. There is a reference in the actual code.

Comment: Could you explain why this behaves the way it does? I'm relatively new to JavaScript and would like to learn as much as I can about it. @qwertymk

Comment: @JLaw [**Take a look at this answer for a better explanation**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7746522/465546)

Answer (score 6):

`setInterval` isn't working at all.

The first argument should be a **function**, you are passing it the return value of `alert()` which isn't a function.

Use the three argument version:

```
setInterval(function,time,array_of_arguments_to_call_function_with);
setInterval(alert,2000,['only shown once']);
```

Comment: Oh, you're right. There is a problem elsewhere and my attempt at checking it with alert was sloppy. There is a reference in the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

The way you wrote it it's wrong:

`setInterval()` wants a function and a numerical value: `setInterval(function(){//your code}, timeInterval)`.

Comment: You're right. There is a problem elsewhere and my attempt at checking it with alert was sloppy. There is a reference in the actual code.