# Repeating Code snippets: same snippet works and works not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a piece of code that looks like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#question"+window.random).css("background-color","pink")
},250);
```

It repeats with other colors in the same function. The first time it works but not the second and so on. That means it just changes the color for one time. In the console it says `undefined`.

Ben

Comment: What is `window.random`?

Comment: you can ignore window.random it´s just a global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using setInterval like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
   $("#question"+window.random).css("background-color","pink")
},250);
```

Comment: same outcome and I got some other documents with simmilar problems.

Comment: are there any known issues for chrome 30?

Comment: You should check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971871/setinterval-not-working-firing-only-once-in-google-chrome-extension