# How to continuously .replace() words inside editable <div> with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple IDE, all it will do is colour code certain syntax. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to replace something like `var` with `<span id="var">var</span>`. The `.replace()` works when the page firsts loads, but not after you start typing, even though it's running on an interval.

The live code is here [codepen.io/Alanay/pen/goLgdx](https://codepen.io/Alanay/pen/goLgdx)

Here's just the JS:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].contentEditable = 'true';

function syntax() {
  var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML;
  var res = div.replace("IDE", "Test");
  document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = res;
}
setInterval(syntax(), 500)
```

Comment: `setInterval(syntax, 500)` (as stated in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Comment: No idea how but it worked, thanks! Any idea how to make it stop typing from the front now though?

Comment: You need to pass the function itself, which is `syntax`. What you did was pass its return value, which is `undefined`. As for your follow-up: do the research. Lots of it. Posting a question here is that absolute *last* thing you want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setInterval not working (firing only once) in Google Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971871/setinterval-not-working-firing-only-once-in-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: Thanks, and I will reseach on it. I think this will be a fun project.

Comment: Tip: think about function definition and reference as separate from function execution.  When you use `setInterval`, you want to just pass a reference to the function, because you're saying *"don't execute it immediately, but later"*.  Whenever you see parenthesis `()`, it's a clue that function is execution happening right there, so you're actually passing the **return value** to setInterval - in this case the original code is the same as `setInterval(undefined, 500)`.  That's why nothing is happening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's I will explain why it hadn't worked with your code.

The `setInterval` method takes 2 params, the function you want to run and `delay` of next execution in milliseconds.

When you call the function with parentheses like `syntax()` it will give you the function output i.e

In below code the `sum` function does summation of 2 numbers and showing it in `span` element.

Basically `return` statement stops function execution and gives output.

```js
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b
}

// will print 3;
let sumDiv = document.getElementById('sum');
sumDiv.innerHTML = sum(1, 2);
```

```html
The sum is <span id='sum'></span>
```

If you don't have `return` statement, the function automatically will return `undefined`.

In the below code I am doing addition of 2 numbers, but not returning them and function returns `undefined`.

```js
function sum(a, b) {
    a + b
}

// will print 3;
let sumDiv = document.getElementById('sum');
sumDiv.innerHTML = sum(1, 2);
```

```html
The sum is <span id='sum'></span>
```

Let's return to `setInterval` and to our `syntax` function.

When you call `setInterval(syntax(), 500)`, your `syntax()` function executes and returns `undefined` as `setInterval` first argument function.

You just need to pass your `syntax` function **without calling**.

`setInterval(syntax, 500)`

The above code will work, because you are just passing your function to be executed each `500` milliseconds, instead of it's returned value which is `undefined` and will cause wrong behavior.

You can read more about `undefined` type and `return` statement [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) respectively. They are very important parts of JavaScript and I suggest you to spend little bit time to read about them.

Answer (score 0):

your **syntax** is wrong. Just set it to setInterval(functionname_without_paranthesis, time_in_ms).

Just set it to setInterval(syntax, 500)