# Why does the setInterval callback execute only once?

Tags: javascript, callback, setinterval

I have this counter I made but I want it to run forever, it's really simple, what am I doing wrong here?

```
function timer() {
  console.log("timer!")
}

window.setInterval(timer(), 1000)
```

Comment: The problem is `timer()` invokes the function-object that resulted from evaluating `timer` and then passes the result (`undefined`) to `setTimeout`. So, don't invoke it. Instead, just pass the function-object: `setInterval(timer, 1000)`

Comment: For the same problem with `setTimeout`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7137401/1048572) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3800512/1048572).

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You used a function call instead of a function reference as the first parameter of the setInterval. Do it like this:

```
function timer() {
  console.log("timer!");
}

window.setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

Or shorter (but when the function gets bigger also less readable):

```
window.setInterval( function() {
  console.log("timer!");
}, 1000)
```

Comment: the answer correctly points out that the callback function should not have the "()" in the argument.

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Common_causes_of_memory_leaks_in_extensions#Be_careful_with_setInterval.2FsetTimeout, the shorter version may cause memory leak.

Comment: @CrendKing Both versions have the exact same "issue" (also, that is for extensions and does not affect normal webpages/JS) as it is *object lifetime* that matters.

Comment: That's why I said "may", since OP does not specify his use case. Just pay attention if it is extracted from an Mozilla extension.

Comment: How can we change the interval value, for e.g. I have array[10, 5, 2] and want to call timer() based on the interval defined in array. Thanks!

Comment: You can't with setInterval, but you can mimic this with the setTimeout function.

Answer (score 13):

`setInterval` and `setTimeout` **must** be used with callbacks, like:

```
setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

or unnamed functions:

```
setInterval( function() { console.log("timer!"); }, 1000 );
```

Why your code is not working - when you pass a function as argument to another function with brackets e.g. `doSomething ( someFunc() )` you are passing the result of the function.

When the function is passed as object e.g. `doSomething ( someFunc )` you are passing a callback. This way `someFunc` is passed as reference and it is executed somewhere in the calling function. This is the same as the pointers to functions in other languages.

A common mistake is to use the these two functions as shown at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp). This makes an implicit call to `eval`.