# Reactjs momentjs countdown in days

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

What I trying to achieve is, making a countdown to target day from now. inside of `componentDidMount()` :

```
nowT = moment(new Date()).format("X"); // => 1603551057 (2020-10-24)
targetDay = moment(result.data.created_at).add('30', 'days').format("X"); // => 1606143175 (2020-11-23)
diffTime = targetDay - nowT; // => 2592000
remain = moment.duration(diffTime, 'milliseconds'); // => {milliseconds: 0, seconds: 11, minutes: 43, hours: 0, days: 0, …}

let intervalId = setInterval(this.countdown(remain), 1000);
this.setState({
  counter: intervalId
});
```

First, I get `now` and `targetday` and calculate difference then send remaining to interval. here is `countdown` function:

```
countdown = (r) => {
  let remain = moment.duration(r - 1000, 'milliseconds');
  this.setState({
    currentCount: remain.days() + ':' + remain.hours() + ":" + remain.minutes() + ":" + remain.seconds()
  });
  console.log(remain.days() + ':' + remain.hours() + ":" + remain.minutes() + ":" + remain.seconds()); // => 0:0:43:11
}
```

Problem is it return wrong countdown `0:0:43:11` also it not update in `render`, just show this static countdown, not dynamic. what I have done wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does the setInterval callback execute only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182714/why-does-the-setinterval-callback-execute-only-once)

Comment: Also even after fixing the interval, it's always called with the same parameter. You need to move all calculations into the `coundown` function.

Comment: You are returning the value of `this.countdown()` instead of passing the function reference of `this.countdown`

Comment: @GuyIncognito nope, I moved all calculations into it, no success

Comment: That was just to fix the most obvious errors. I don't get why you calculate everything manually when you could just use Moment to get the result directly.

Comment: @GuyIncognito can you show me how can I do this via moment directly? *(because maybe I don't know momentjs too much, I just started to working with it)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no need to calculate `duration`, once you get difference between `then` and `now` you can get what you want:

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
  nowT = moment();
  targetDay = moment(result.data.created_at).add('30', 'days');
  diffTime = moment(targetDay - nowT);
  timeObj = {
    count_days: diffTime.format('D');
    count_hours: diffTime.format('HH');
    count_minutes: diffTime.format('mm');
    count_seconds: diffTime.format('ss');
  }
}, 1000);
```

Now you can use `setState` to get values in `render`

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the function `this.countdown()` which **returns a value** directly, instead of passing the function reference where you'd want to pass the argument.

If I were to literally interpret your code, what you're doing right now is:

```js
// pseudo-code, serves only as example
setInterval(void, 1000)
```

when what you'd want to be doing is

```js
// pseudo-code - serves only as example
setInterval(this.countdown, 1000)
// this is fine as long as we don't have to pass arguments ^
```

essentially in order to do this, you need to pass the function as a callback with the argument

```js
setInterval(() => this.countdown(remain), 1000)
```

As a final note, don't forget to `clearInterval()` in `componentWillUnmount()` otherwise you might get a memory leak in your application.

Comment: yes, I uesed `clearInterval` already. I used `setInterval(() => this.countdown(remain), 1000)` but still return wrong countdown.

Comment: likely because you put it in `componentDidMount()`. You need to be more specific than just 'wrong countdown'. It depends on what you're trying to achieve