# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at changeColors (colors.js:4)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to create a blinker, which changes the color of the h1 tag every second. For which i have written this code.

JS

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'pink', 'magenta', 'brown'];

function changeColors() {
    document.querySelector('h1').style.color = colors[Math.round(Math.random()*6)];
}

setInterval(changeColors(), 1000)
```

The error that i am getting is : **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
at changeColors (colors.js:4)**

Whenever i seperately run the following code
`document.querySelector('h1').style.color = colors[Math.round(Math.random()*6)];`
it works as it should i.e everytime gives me a different color.

Comment: Can you insert the html for this?

Comment: it should be `setInterval(changeColors, 1000)` (no parens)

Comment: [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15886272) | [Why does the setInterval callback execute only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10182714)

Comment: @adiga wow, we have so many duplicates for this... I'll try to put it in my backlog to try and research them because it seems like they should be linked to each other.

Comment: @VLAZ based on the number of linked questions, this is a common issue. You have the hammer. Why didn't you close it as a duplicate of [Why does the setInterval callback execute only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182714)

Comment: @adiga I got overwhelmed searching for an appropriate dupe. There is many. Got side tracked into exploring those. I'll edit the dupe list if I find good relevant ones.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Removing the parenthesis does the job.

Answer (score 4):

You are directly executing the function without waiting for the interval trigger.

Try this instead;

```js
setInterval(changeColors, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Parentheses should not be included because  () invokes the function immediately.

```js
const colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "pink", "magenta", "brown"];

function changeColors() {
  document.querySelector("h1").style.color =
    colors[Math.round(Math.random() * 6)];
}

setInterval(changeColors, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Colors</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Change Color</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'pink', 'magenta', 'brown'];

function changeColors() {
    document.querySelector('h1').style.color = colors[Math.round(Math.random()*6)];
}

setInterval(function(){
  changeColors(); 
},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem come from the moment you’re executing this JS in your HTML. You must execute it after the h1 was created, otherwise the Query Selector while return an empty element as he can’t find the h1. Moreover you must delete the parentheses of changeColors in the setInterval(), otherwise the function will be executed immediately and just one time.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
         <h1>Title</h1>
         <script>
              colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'pink', 'magenta', 'brown'];

              function changeColors() {
                    document.querySelector('h1').style.color = colors[Math.round(Math.random()*6)];
              }

              setInterval(changeColors, 1000)
          </script>
      </body>
  </html>
```

https://codepen.io/ethanoul/pen/ZEBNOzx

Have a good day :)