# How do you create a graph using Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET 4.5.2 Web Form template that continuously updates?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to create a website which present a number of charts (preferably line graphs) which will actively (in real time) display data as it is being read from a sensor. I have successfully created active live charts in Windows Forms Application, however they do not let display my data on an internet website.

Therefore I have attempted to create a simple graph in an ASP.NET Application using a Web Forms ASP.NET 4.5.2 template. The Default.aspx.cs code was simple and as I was trying to plot a point on a graph every 500 ms whenever button 1 is pressed. However when I opened the application in my browser pressing button 1 caused the timer to activate, but the graph remained blank (flickered on the screen). Please can somebody help me create a chart that can actively update to display new data as it is captured/generated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        int i = 0;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer1.Interval = 1000;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer1.Enabled = true;
        } 

        protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(i, i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Signal - https://www.asp.net/signalr. 
Your code above uses webforms. Although it's doable but I prefer you use newer framework like MVC for your front-end/web.

Comment: the link you provided has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your server side approach won't work in this case:
You need to use either:

- server pulling on client [make ajax call to run multiple times with setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712979/make-ajax-call-to-run-multiple-times-with-setinterval)
- or use web socket  [HTML5 web socket with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171782/html5-web-socket-with-asp-net)

to get your latest data for the chart. That means you need to change you web-form a bit to expose web service that will provide you latest data and update UI to consume this via javascript.

Comment: Thank you. This has helped a lot.