# Weird delay error thing

Tags: javascript, html

So, I was making a program in html that would convert any decimal number to a binary number, which was working perfectly, then I tried to modify it, and screwed it up somehow. The problem seems to be it takes the value at the start of the runtime, rather than always grabbing it at the moment, but it wasn't doing that before. And, I have no idea why it's doing it, and I'm not completely sure what I'd even look up to look for this kind of error, especially when I have no idea what is wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type = "number" id = 'decimal'></input><br/>
        <a id = 'binary'></a>
        <script>
            setInterval(convert(),1);
            function convert() {
                var nNum = "";
                var num = document.getElementById('decimal').value;
                while(num != 0) {
                    nNum = (num % 2) + nNum;
                    num = Math.floor(num/2);
                }
                document.getElementById('binary').innerHTML = nNum;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

any and all help is greatly appreciated. c:

Comment: Should be `setInterval(convert,. . .` not `setInterval(convert(),. . .`

Comment: Related: [JS setInterval executes only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746505/js-setinterval-executes-only-once)

Comment: ok. That solves the problem. Weird it was working previously though with that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<script>
    setInterval(convert,1);
    function convert() {
        var nNum = "";
        var num = document.getElementById('decimal').value;
        while(num != 0) {
            nNum = (num % 2) + nNum;
            num = Math.floor(num/2);
        }
        document.getElementById('binary').innerHTML = nNum;
    }
</script>
```

When you pass function as parameter of function you don't call it `convert()`, you only pass it `convert`

Comment: yea. It's like the other guy said. I find it odd though because it worked last time I'd used "convert()"

Comment: @JoshuaReid If an answer solves your problem you should accept it so question is marked as answered.

Comment: Ok. Yea. Sorry. ^^other guy answered in a comment, so I did not have the ability to do that.