# setTimeout does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl

I want to load an OWL file before executing other (visualisation-)scripts. To do this I tried everything from

```
$(document).ready
```

to

```
function visualize (file) {
if (!file)
    {setTimeout(visualize(file), 2000)}
else
    {jQuery(function($){visFeaturePool.init(file)})}}
```

I think it has to be possible with the setTimeout but that isn't working. I throws the error: 
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, so it doesn't wait, it just recalls the visualize function untill the stack is full.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't have a problem, you can't pass parameters to the function you want `setTimeout` to execute.

Comment: Duplicate of [Calling functions with setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800512/calling-functions-with-settimeout)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Instead of

```
// #1
setTimeout(visualize(file), 2000);
```

you want

```
// #2
setTimeout(function() {
    visualize(file);
}, 2000);
```

or on modern browsers, you can provide arguments to pass to the function after the delay:

```
// #3
setTimeout(visualize, 2000, file);
```

Those three explained:

1. (As SLaks mentions) This calls `visualize` *immediately*, and then passes its return value into `setTimeout` (and since `visualize` calls itself, it keeps calling itself recursively and you end up with a **stack overflow** error).
2. This passes a function reference into `setTimeout` that, when called, will call `visualize` and pass it the `file` argument (with its value as it is *then*). The function we're passing into `setTimeout` will have access to the `file` argument, even though your code has run and returned, because that function is a *closure* over the context in which it was created, which includes `file`. More: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) Note that the `file` variable's value is read as of when the timer *fires*, not when you set it up.
3. This passes the `visualize` function reference into `setTimeout` (note we don't have `()` or `(file)` after it) and also passes `file` into `setTimeout`, using its value as of when you set up the call. Later, in modern environments, `setTimeout` will pass that on to the function when calling it later.

There's an important difference between #2 and #3: With #2, if `file` is changed between when `setTimeout` is called and the timer expires, `visualize` will see `file`'s new value. With #3, though, it won't. Both have their uses. Here's an example of that difference:

```js
let file = 1;

// #2, using "file" when the timer fires, not when you set it up
setTimeout(function() { visualize(file); }, 2000); // Shows 2

// #3, using "file" right away when setting up the timer
setTimeout(visualize, 2000, file); // Shows 1

file = 2;

function visualize(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

If you needed #3's behavior of immediately reading `file` (rather than waiting until the timer fires) in an environment that didn't support extra arguments to `setTimeout`, you could do this:

```
// #4 (for environments that don't support #3)
setTimeout(visualize.bind(null, file), 2000);
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help, for some reason everyone insists to use setTimeout(function(file), milliseconds); which doesn't work at all, this saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout(visualize(file), 2000)` calls `visualize` **immediately** and passes its result to `setTimeout`, just like any other function call.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function visualize (file) {
  if (!file)
    {setTimeout(function(){visualize(file);}, 2000)}
  else
    {jQuery(function($){visFeaturePool.init(file)})}}
```

This way you are giving setTimeout an anonymous function that will be executed when scheduled, and you can pass parameters to visualize using a closure like `file`.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(visualize, 2000, file);
```

will also work.