# onclick multiple functions with delay

Tags: function, onclick, delay

I need something like that:

```
onClick="function1(); function2();"
```

with a small delay between the functions.
I **DON'T WANT** to call function2 at the end of function1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onclick="functionCaller";

<script>
function functionCaller(){
    function1();
    setTimeout(function2, 500); //this will call function2 after 500 millisecons.
}
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried this but the setTimeout() doesn't work. It does the function instant. I don't know why. Tried .delay(3000) too, same problem.

Comment: Did you make sure to NOT add () on function 2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375962/settimeout-does-not-work here i found my mistake. Now it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, if you need to specify parameters for function2 you need to do this :)