# setTimeout() is not waiting

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout

I am trying to make a seconds countdown with Javascript.

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="ban_container" class="error center">Please wait
        <span id="ban_countdown" style="font-weight:bold">
        45</span>
        seconds before trying again
</div>
```

And my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var seconds = <?php echo $user->getBlockExpiryRemaining(); ?>;

    function countdown(element) {
        var el = document.getElementById(element);

        if (seconds === 0) {
            document.getElementById("ban_container").innerHTML = "done";
            return;
        }
        else {
            el.innerHTML = seconds;
            seconds--;
            setTimeout(countdown(element), 1000);
        }
    }

    countdown('ban_countdown');
</script>
```

However for some reason, it is not waiting the timeout time, but instead executes `countdown` right away so that when I refresh the page it just displays "done" right away. I know it is actually being executed multiple times because if I do `innerHTML += seconds + " ";` it counts down from 45. Why is the timeout being bypassed?

Comment: Is your script in its own file or in the .php file?

Comment: Duplicate of [Calling functions with setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800512/calling-functions-with-settimeout)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`setTimeout(countdown(element), 1000);` executes your function with that argument and passes the result into `setTimeout`. You don't want that.

Instead, execute an anonymous function that calls your function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    countdown(el);  // You used `el`, not `element`?
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Mike: PS: Also you can do `setTimeout(countdown, t);` if you don't need to pass anything to the function. ;)

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked this subtlety as well.

Answer (score 8):

If you'd like to pass an argument to a function by `setTimeout`, try this:

```
setTimeout(countdown, 1000, element);
```

The syntax of setTimeout is the following:

```
setTimeout(function,milliseconds,param1,param2,...)
```

Comment: Note: According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), passing parameters like this only works for IE >= 10.

Answer (score 4):

It is because setTimeout is asynchroneous. Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   countdown('ban_countdown'); //or elemement
}, 1000);
```

This will make the function countdown execute after 1000 miliseconds.