# How to prevent some scripts on page to not refresh with page reload

Tags: javascript

I have a website in which I've added a code with which it reloads every 1-2 mins.

All I want to do this is, place a timer code there, and put a go-to "X" URL script after that time is completed.

But timer and that script got refresh after page reloads?

How to prevent and at the same time implement timer and go to a URL?.

Any Ideas?

Comment: @ail Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14266817/10811334) what you're looking for?

Comment: @ycao I can't do that.

Comment: that's why need some help.

Comment: You don't know how or it's impossible?

Comment: set a cookie with whether or not the timer has been completed. on page reload, check that cookie. If it exists, no need to run the countdown again

Answer (score 2):

You can't refresh a page and keep it's script not refreshed, but... you can use window.localStorage or document.cookie!

- I would [check if the cookie exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968196/check-cookie-if-cookie-exists).
- If not: [create a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26176128/12603016), make it's value the current
  [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).
- If there is a cookie, [compare it's Date to the current](https://stackoverflow.com/a/497790/12603016) to get
  the time passed. Then, you can redirect as wanted and [delete the

  cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2144404/12603016).

Comment: Exactly - when you page refresh - variables get reset.