# setTimeout nuances in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I'm trying to understand how the callback function works inside the setTimeout function. I'm aware the format is: `setTimeout(callback, delay)` I wrote a little test script to explore this.

test1.js

```
console.log("Hello")

setTimeout(function () { console.log("Goodbye!") }, 5000)

console.log("Non-blocking")
```

This works as expected, printing `Hello <CRLF> Non-blocking` and then 5 seconds later, prints `Goodbye!`

I then wanted to bring the function outside of the setTimeout like this:

```
console.log("Hello")

setTimeout(goodbye(), 5000)

console.log("Non-blocking")

function goodbye () {
    console.log("Goodbye")
}
```

but it doesn't work and there isn't a 5 second delay between `Non-blocking` and `Goodbye!`, they print straight after each other.

It works if I remove the brackets from the function call in the timeout, like this:

```
setTimeout(goodbye, 5000)
```

but this doesn't make sense to me because that's not how you call a function. Futhermore, how would you pass arguments to the function if it looked like this?!

```
var name = "Adam"    

console.log("Hello")

setTimeout(goodbye(name), 5000)

console.log("Non-blocking")

function goodbye (name) {
    console.log("Goodbye "+name)
}
```

My question is really, why doesn't it work when there are parameters in the function, despite the fact the setTimeout is being provided with a valid function with the correct syntax?

Comment: It makes perfect sense, you don't want to ***call*** the function, you want to reference it so it can be called later by `setTimeout`, hence no parentheses. This doesn't just go for Node, it's basic javascript.

Comment: [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642),  [Calling functions with setTimeout()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800512)

Comment: If you replace the variable with the function definition, you will notice the difference: Replacing `goodbye` in  `setTimeout(goodbye(), 5000)` becomes `setTimeout(function goodbye() { ... ) }(), 5000)`. Do you notice the trailing `()`? They don't appear in `setTimeout(function () { ... }, 5000)`

Comment: And if you think about it, it behaves exactly as expected. `setTimeout` is not magical, it basically behaves like any other function: Arguments are evaluated before they are passed to the callee. If you have `foo(bar())`, then `bar` is executed first and its return value is passed to `foo`. That's how *every* function call works in JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By putting the parentheses after your function name, you are effectively calling it, and not passing the function as a callback.

To provide parameters to the function you are calling:

1. You can pass an anon function. `setTimeout(function(){goodbye(name)}, 5000);`
2. Or, you can pass the arguments as a third parameter. `setTimeout(goodbye, 5000, name);`

Look at this question: [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Comment: Ah that makes sense! I'm guessing the reason it doesn't call the anon function straight away is because it's being declared and not called? Is that right?

Comment: Yes. It would have been called if the code was somthing like this. 
`setTimeout(function(){ goodbye(name); }(), 5000);`

Notice the parentheses at the end of the anon function.

Answer (score 3):

No matter where you place it, `goodbye(name)` executes the function **immediately**. So you should instead pass the *function itself* to `setTimeout()`: `setTimeout(goodbye, 5000, name)`.

Answer (score 3):

When you use it like this:

```
setTimeout(goodbye(), 5000);
```

it will first call `goodbye` to get its return value, then it will call `setTimeout` using the returned value.

You should call `setTimeout` with a reference to a callback function, i.e. only specifying the name of the function so that you get its reference instead of calling it:

```
setTimeout(goodbye, 5000);
```

To make a function reference when you want to send a parameter to the callback function, you can wrap it in a function expression:

```
setTimeout(function() { goodbye(name); }, 5000);
```

---

You *can* use parantheses in the call, but then the function should return a function reference to the actual callback function:

```
setTimeout(createCallback(), 5000);

function createCallback() {
  return function() {
    console.log("Goodbye");
  };
}
```