# Wait for all XHR on a page to finish in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

In my javascript file for a page, I would like to execute some scripts after all the XHR have returned. I know that there is `ajaxStop()` for XHR requests through jquery, but since I am using Mithril and it has its own wrapper around Ajax, I can't really use `ajaxStop()`.
I have also tried some other solutions like

```
function isAllXhrComplete(){
    window.activeAjaxCount--;
    if (window.activeAjaxCount === 0){
        //execute something here.
    }

}

(function(open) {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
        this.addEventListener("load", isAllXhrComplete());
        open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);


(function(send) {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (data) {
        window.activeAjaxCount++;
        send.call(this, data);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

But it seems that since all the XHR calls are fired separately, the `window.activeAjaxCount` would always be 1 or 0, thus triggering the execution of script on every finished XHR request.

Is there any good ways to wait for all XHR requests to return?

Comment: It is probably a duplicate to [Calling functions with setTimeout()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800512/calling-functions-with-settimeout). Even though it is about `setTimeout` the reason is still the same.

Comment: While one problem is that you're calling `isAllXhrComplete()` instead of passing it, I really wouldn't overwrite the original methods to do what you want. You can do this by creating a function that manages a group of XHR calls.

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is here:

```
this.addEventListener("load", isAllXhrComplete());
```

the `isAllXhrComplete` is not passed as callback, because you immediately call it. Instead the result of the `isAllXhrComplete()` call is passed.

You have to write:

```
this.addEventListener("load", isAllXhrComplete);
```

Beside that you should really take care when you wrap existing functions. A correct way would be:

```
(function(send) {
   XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {
      window.activeAjaxCount++;
      return send.apply(this, arguments);
   };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

The important part is that you `return` the result of the original function, and that you use `apply` to pass all possible arguments. Otherwise you might break code in future, if the signature of those functions is changed.

Your need to do the same with the `open` wrapper:

```
(function(open) {
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    this.addEventListener("load", isAllXhrComplete);
    return open.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```