# setTimeout instantly executing

Tags: javascript

Javascript is executing this code instantly, however, I need it to wait 2 milliseconds before executing it, as scripted in `setTimeout(doIt(i),2000);`

Why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var colors= ["red","pink","green"];
    function doIt(i){
        i++
        console.log(i);
        console.log("didIt");
        $('body').append("<style>body{background:"+i+";}</style>");
        if(i==2){
        }
        else{
            test(i);
        }

    }

    function test(i){
        setTimeout(doIt(i),2000);
    }
    test(0);
</script>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` first argument is a reference to a function

Comment: Difference between a function expression and a function invocation: the parentheses. One is a function, the other is a value that is returned by the function.

Comment: Tutorial here: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2014/11/javascript-settimeout-executes-function-immediately.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the most common mistake. Change your code to this:

```
function test(i){
    setTimeout(function() {
        doIt(i);
    }, 2000);
}
```

You were directly invoking the `doIt` method instead of just passing the reference to the `setTimeout` callback by writing `(i)` after `doIt`.

Another way of writing directly using the `bind()` method:

```
function test(i) {
    setTimeout(doIt.bind(null, i), 2000);
}
```

It's all given here:

1. [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)
2. [Calling functions with setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800512/calling-functions-with-settimeout)