# Passing functions and variables as arguments to map() in Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arguments

I want to pass a prop called `verified` through each map function and I am having difficulty setting it up.

**UPDATE**:

Passing `verified` to renderContinents works, but when add a parameter to renderCountry like this:

```
  {continent.countries.map(renderCountry(null, verified))}
```

My output is blank. Shouldn't this work though?

Updated code:

```
  const renderCities = cities => {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          <input
              onChange={onChange}
              type="checkbox"/>
        {cities.name}
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const renderCountries = ({country, verified}) => {
    console.log("came to country");
    return (
      <div className="city-location"> 
        <label>
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              type="checkbox"/>
          {country.name}
        </label>
        {country.cities.map(renderCities)}
      </div>
    ); 
  };



function onChange(e) {
  console.log('checkbox verified:', (e.target.verified));
}


class AreasComponent extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
        };
        this.renderContinents = this.renderContinents.bind(this);
    }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchAllAreas(); 
  }

  renderContinents(verified, continent) {
    console.log("came to continent");
      return(
        <div className="continent-location">
          <label>
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
                type="checkbox"/>
             {continent.name}
          </label>

          {continent.countries.map(renderCountries(null, verified))}

        </div>
    )
  } 


  render() { 
    if (!this.props.verified || !this.props.areas) {
      return <div>Loading Areas...</div>
    }
    return(
        <div> 
          {this.props.areas.map(this.renderContinents.bind(this, this.props.verified))}
        </div>
      );
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchAllAreas, checkArea}, dispatch);
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { areas: state.areas.all,
           verified:state.areas.verified
  };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AreasComponent);
```

My other problem is the `onChange(e)` function. It's global so it works when I click any checkbox, but I want to make it so that when onChange is clicked, it can take in a parameter and dispatch the action `checkArea`, which, to me means it has to be bound and should also be fed as a parameter. I tried this:

```
  {this.props.areas.map(this.renderContinents.bind(this, this.props.verified, this.props.checkArea))}
```

but it returns a blank result. Is it possible to send a function into a map () parameter and is there a way to get renderCountry/renderCity to work with parameters?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3800512/497418. Don't let the title fool you, it's a red herring of the underlying issue which is that you're calling the function immediately, rather than passing a function to be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the simplest way for `renderCountry/renderCity` to call `onChange()` with `checkArea` action is to put them inside `AreasComponent` (i.e. as member functions). So they can access both `onChange` and `checkArea`.

```
class AreasComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchAllAreas();
    }

    onChange(e, type) {
        console.log('checkbox verified:', this.props.verified);
        // call checkArea() here with your parameters
        this.props.checkArea(type);
    }

    renderCities(cities) {
        return (
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input
                        onChange={e => this.onChange(e, 'city')}
                        type="checkbox"/>
                    {cities.name}
                </label>
            </div>
        );
    };

    renderCountries(country) {
        console.log("came to country");
        return (
            <div className="city-location">
                <label>
                    <input
                        onChange={e => this.onChange(e, 'country')}
                        type="checkbox"/>
                    {country.name}
                </label>
                {
                    country.cities.map(this.renderCities)
                }
            </div>
        );
    };

    renderContinents(continent) {
        console.log("came to continent");
        return(
            <div className="continent-location">
                <label>
                    <input
                        onChange={e => this.onChange(e, 'continent')}
                        type="checkbox"/>
                    {continent.name}
                </label>
                {
                    continent.countries.map(this.renderCountries)
                }
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.props.verified || !this.props.areas) {
            return <div>Loading Areas...</div>
        }
        return(
            <div>
                {
                    this.props.areas.map(this.renderContinents)
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({ fetchAllAreas, checkArea}, dispatch);
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        areas: state.areas.all,
        verified: state.areas.verified
    };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AreasComponent);
```

Comment: I actually figured this out 3 days ago but just gonna mark this as the correct answer since it was very similar to what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 5):

When you `.bind` parameters, those parameters become the first value(s) passed to the function. You should have noticed that when looking at the `console.log` output.

I.e. when you do

```
var bar = foo.bind(this, x, y);
bar(z);
```

you get the values in this order:

```
function foo(x, y, z) {}
```

You have switch the order of parameters in your function:

```
renderContinent(checked, continent) {
  // ...
}
```

---

However, you can just keep the code you have. You don't have to pass the value to `renderContinents`.

In order to pass it to `renderContinents` etc, either `.bind` it or put the call inside another function:

```
continent.countries.map(renderCountries.bind(null, verified))
// or
continent.countries.map(country => renderCountries(country, verified))
```

Comment: Thanks! I can now renderContinents. Just a quick question, what does the null parameter signify? When I used this code to renderCountries both country and verified appear to be null. I updated my code, thanks again!

Comment: The null signifies the 'this' the function will be bound to. That is primarily what `.bind` is used for. But -as you can see-, it can also bind parameters.

It can bind as many parameters as you like, but if you want to bind parameters, you're going to have to provide a 'this' as well. 
If you don't care what 'this' will be, null will do just fine.