# when trying to add delay in Pusher client script it do not work

Tags: pusher

I was trying to add some delay to the response in Pusher

**code**

```
Pusher.logToConsole = true;
            var message;
            var pusher = new Pusher('someKeykjhkjklhl', {
              cluster: 'eu',
              encrypted: true
            });

            var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
            channel.bind('fileUploadJob', function(data) {
                 setTimeout(showMessage(data), 3000);

            });

            function showMessage(data)
            {
                    toastr.success(data.message,{ fadeAway: 1000 });

            }
```

but it is just working like normal

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
channel.bind('fileUploadJob', function(data) {
    setTimeout(function() { showMessage(data) }, 3000);
});
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3800526/3475350
this link will tell you what actually happened.