# setInterval and setTimeout in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, settimeout, setinterval

I am learning Typescript and am trying to print a console message a number of times over a period of time. **But in my test this happens once**, you know the reason?

The code is below:

```
 class Class {
    private msg: string;
    constructor(msg: string) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    private printMsg(): void {
        console.log(this.msg);
    };
    public repeatMsg(): void {
        let intervalo = setInterval(this.printMsg(), 2000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            clearInterval(intervalo);
        }, 40000);
    }
}

let test: Class;
test = new Class("Hello");
test.repeatMsg();
```

Comment: Remove the `()`, you're calling the function immediately, `setInterval` expects a function reference, like you provided via anonymous function in the timeout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling functions with setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800512/calling-functions-with-settimeout)

Comment: Removing `()` would break `this.msg`. Using `this.pringMsg.bind(this)` would work though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem in your code is there:

```
setInterval(this.printMsg(), 2000);
```

`setInterval` accepts a function as a first parameter. Expression `this.printMsg()` is a call of the function, and is `void` actually. There are two ways to fix it. Use lambda:

```
setInterval(() = > this.printMsg(), 2000);
```

Or use bind:

```
setInterval(this.printMsg.bind(this), 2000);
```