# Why won't setInterval work on an object method I have made?

Tags: javascript, object, setinterval

I am trying to create a simple animation that makes a car image most across the screen (learning exercise). I am trying to make it happen with setInterval, and this doesn't seem to be working. The image is stationary. See code below:

```
var Car = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};

Car.prototype.draw = function() {
  var carHtml = '<img src="http://nostarch.com/images/car.png">';

Car.prototype.moveRight = function(distance) {
  this.x;

  this.carElement.css({
    left: distance,
    top: this.y
  });
};

var tesla = new Car(20, 20);
tesla.draw();

function runOnInterval(fn, arg) {
  setInterval(function () {
    fn(arg);
  }, 1000);
}

runOnInterval(tesla.moveRight(), 10);
```

As I said, this results in the image being stationary, and an error message in the console saying "fn is not a function". Can anyone tell me what I am missing here? Thank you.

Comment: you are passing the result of calling a function `tesla.moveRight()` as `fn` .... you need to pass the function itself `tesla.moveRight` (you'll also probably have a `this` issue I'm guessing, depends if you know what you are doing)

Answer (score 2):

Arguments are evaluated eagerly. If you have `foo(bar())` then `bar` is called first and its return value is passed to `foo`.

That's what happens in

```
runOnInterval(tesla.moveRight(), 10);
```

It calls `tesla.moveRight()` and passes the return value (`undefined`) to `runOnInterval` which will then error because `undefined` is not a function.

You have to pass `tesla.moveRight` itself **and** if you have to bind its `this` value to the correct object:

```
runOnInterval(tesla.moveRight.bind(tesla), 10);
// or
runOnInterval(function(x) { tesla.moveRight(x); }, 10);
```

---

See also:

- [Calling functions with setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3800512/218196)
- [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. However, neither of your code snippets work.

Comment: Yes it does: https://jsfiddle.net/b0rLnzxk/ (needed to fix the second one though)