# How to add colours when a page is reloaded using javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am have created an array of colors. I am trying to use colors.forEach inside ready function to call addBox for each color in this array. The plan is that I see that all the colors have been added when the page is reloaded. Let me know if you need html code pls

```
function addBox(color) {
    $('#colors').prepend('<div class="item" style="background-color: ' + color + ';"></div>');
}


var colors = ['22ac5e', 'd68236', '770077'];

// I think my problem lies after this line
$(document).ready(function () {
//  var colors = ['22ac5e', 'd68236', '770077'];
    colors.forEach(addBox(color))

});
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling functions with setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800512/calling-functions-with-settimeout) Although you are not using `setTimeout` explicitly, the answer is the same; put the callback in there without parentheses.

Comment: The online tutorial that I am using doesn't cover setTimeout(). I do apologise for the similarities or overlap in topic covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're providing the *result* of `addBox(color)` to the `forEach()` loop, you're not actually providing the *reference* of that function so it can be called.

There's a couple of ways you can amend your code so that it will work. Firstly, an anonymous function:

```
colors.forEach(function(color) {
  addBox(color)
});
```

Or an arrow function if you don't need IE support at all:

```
colors.forEach(color => addBox(color));
```

Finally note that the hex colours in your CSS will need the `#` prefix:

```
'... style="background-color: #' + color + ';" ...'
```

Comment: Rory beat me to it, but here is a jsfiddle to help out: https://jsfiddle.net/Lq76a3ky/

Comment: No problem, glad to help