# Both .then and .catch are being executed in the same block of code

Tags: javascript, react-native

so I try to prevent from item to get into an array if it's already there once. Basically, the function is doing its job and not allowing to insert an item that already exists. But, all the error messages that I put using .catch and else are being shown on the screen, **meaning that both .then and .catch are being executed** and I don't understand why...
This is my code:

```
 function onBuy() {
        const email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
        const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('parties').doc(String(name)).collection('users').doc(String(email));
        const ref2 = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(String(email));
        ref.get()
        .then((doc) => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
                ref2.get()
                .then((doc2) => {
                    if (doc2.exists) {
                        ref.set({
                            firstname: doc2.data().firstname,
                            lastname: doc2.data().lastname,
                            phone: doc2.data().phone
                        }).then(
                            ref2.update({ parties: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(name) }).then(
                                Actions.pop()))
                        .catch(Alert.alert('fail'));
                    }
                }).catch(Alert.alert('fail'));                   
            }
            else {
                Alert.alert('this user already bought a ticket');
            }
        })
        .catch(Alert.alert('this user already bought a ticket'));
    }
```

I tried to search for solutions but didn't found an answer.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Only use the Stack Snippet to show a working example. Otherwise just use code block with \`code here\` or \`\`\` for multiline code \`\`\`

Comment: If something in the .then block throws it'll go into the catch. Whatever catch returns is how the promise resolves (alert returns undefined). None of your .then functions seem to return anything as well.

Comment: You must pass a callback to `catch`. You are calling `Alert.alert()` immediately

Comment: I would also change the message depending on the `catch` that is being called so I know which one is being called. You have multiple similar alerts which will make tracking down a bug an issue.

Comment: Kind of related: [Calling functions with setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3800512/691711) in that you are calling a function where you should be passing a function reference.  In this instance, `catch()` is `setTimeout()`.  You're doing it correctly with the `then()` so follow the same pattern.

Comment: @HMR thanks! I added the alert as a returned object and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Solution.
Just passed the Alert.alert() in an arrow function in the .catch.
Like so:

```
    function onBuy() {
    const email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
    const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('parties').doc(String(name)).collection('users').doc(String(email));
    const ref2 = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(String(email));
    ref.get()
    .then((doc) => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
            ref2.get()
            .then((doc2) => {
                if (doc2.exists) {
                    ref.set({
                        firstname: doc2.data().firstname,
                        lastname: doc2.data().lastname,
                        phone: doc2.data().phone
                    }).then(
                        ref2.update({ parties: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(name) }).then(
                            Actions.pop()))
                    .catch(() => Alert.alert('error', 'oops, something went wrong'));
                }
            }).catch(() => Alert.alert('error', 'Sorry, something went wrong'));                   
        }
        else {
            Alert.alert('Purches fails', 'You have already bought a ticket to this party!');
        }
    })
    .catch(() => Alert.alert('fails', 'user problem'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to realize that **.then** passes results/errors to the next **.then/catch**. You did not specify a callback to **.catch**; all you are doing is calling the **Alert.alert()** immediately after **.then**.

So you should have

```
someAsyncOperation(params)
 .then(function(result){
  // Do something with the result
 })
 .catch(function(error){
 // Handle error
});
```

Also note that all your **.then** seems not to be returning anything.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty new to this, so it is very helpful for me :) @Debaryoh