# How to automatically update weather data (JSON) on a website using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, setinterval, weather-api

Hi I'm trying to create a website that shows you current weather(in 3 cities for now). My problem is that I don't know how I can get only the JSON data to update when the switch is in the ON position. (So I don't want to reload the page after the interval I just want to automatically update the temperature etc. after a certain timeperiod.)

Here is a picture of the website:[image]

Here is my implementation. Can't seem to figure this out since in my opinion this should work :D Been staring at this for way too long now.

### JavaScript

```
function setup() {
  var dropinput = document.getElementById("city-dropdown");
  var value = dropinput.options[dropinput.selectedIndex].value;
  var url = api + value + units + apiKey;
  fetch(url).then(
    function(response) {
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
      response.status);
      return;
    }
    response.json().then(function(data) {
      document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = 'Temperature: ' + data.main.temp + ' Celsius'
      document.getElementById("wind").innerHTML = 'Wind: ' + data.wind.speed + ' m/s'
      document.getElementById("humidity").innerHTML = 'Humidity: ' + data.main.humidity + '%'
    });
    }
  )

}

var interval = null;

function autoupdate() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("switch");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    interval = setInterval(setup(), 1000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="slideshow.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="setup()">
<div class="container">

  <h1>Check the weather!</h1>
  <fieldset>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <select name="city" id="city-dropdown">
          <option value="Helsinki">Helsinki</option>
          <option value="Turku">Turku</option>
          <option value="Kuusamo">Kuusamo</option>
      </select>
      <button class="nappi" type="button" onclick="setup()">Get weather</button>
    </form>
  </fieldset>
  <p id="temp">Temperature: </p>
  <p id="wind">Wind: </p>
  <p id="humidity">Humidity: </p>

</div>

<div class="update">
    <p id="autoupdate">Auto-update:</p>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" id="switch" onclick="autoupdate()">
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov They're already getting the data.  That won't help at all.

Comment: 2 things.  Firstly, remove the brackets after `setup` here `interval = setInterval(setup, 1000);`  This will pass a reference to the function, not the result of executing it.  Secondly, don't use an interval.  Use a timeout and create another when the call is complete, so you don't end up overlapping calls that take longer than your interval.

Comment: `setInterval(setup(), 1000);` should be `setInterval(setup, 1000);`  You're trying to run `setup`'s return value repeatedly, but that function doesn't return a function.

Comment: @Archer awesome this did the trick thanks! I didn't need to change the setInterval though.

Comment: @MatiasBerglund Just have a think about what would happen if the server started to take longer than a second to respond.  Also, ask yourself if there's anything to be gained by using `setInterval` over `setTimeout`.  I will *always* recommend using `setTimeout` for repeated API calls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling functions with setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800512/calling-functions-with-settimeout)

Answer (score -1):

you need to do this :

```
setInterval(function(){setup()}, 1000);
```

Comment: Or just `setInterval(setup, 1000);`, which is a lot shorter. It's completely unnecessary to wrap a function inside a function like this.  `setup` is perfectly callable on its own.