# Pass "this" throw functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to store the value of an input (in an array) each time it is updated.
I have multiple inputs with the structure:

```
<input class="inf" key="213" type="CUSTOM" value="val">
```

Then I had this working function:

```
$('.inf').on('keyup', function () {
    clearTimeout(temp2);
    temp2= setTimeout(updateValues.call(this), doneTypingInterval);
});
```

But the setTimeout doesn't work, so I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800512/calling-functions-with-settimeout) and changed it to:

```
temp2= setTimeout(function () {updateValues.call(this);}, doneTypingInterval);
```

Now, `setTimeout` is working but, when `updateValues` is reached, all 3 variables are "undefined".

updateValues function:

```
var updateValues= function(){
            
 key=$(this).attr("key");
 type=$(this).attr("type");
 value=this.value;
                
    upd={
        "name" : '"'+key+'"',
        "type" : '"'+type+'"',
        "value" : '"'+value+'"'
    };
 nw = nw.concat(upd);
 console.log(nw);
};
```

The problem is that the `this` object in `updateValues` is what I passed with the `call`. Any suggestions?

Comment: _"But timeout doesn't work"_ - It does, but you don't understand how `Function.prototype.call()` works.

Comment: And why `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Try with `setTimeout(updateValues.bind(this), ...)` or `setTimeout(_ => updateValues.call(this), ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer to your problem is to use `.bind()` instead of `.call()`:

```
temp2 = setTimeout(updateValues.bind(this), doneTypingInterval);
```

or use the arrow function:

```
temp2 = setTimeout(() => { updateValues.call(this); }, doneTypingInterval);
```

More on how `this` works can be found in [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/7080548)