# I cant get set interval to work no matter what I try

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I dont know whats going on. Heres my code:

```
   setInterval(testI(),1000);

   function testI(){
        console.log("I ran");
   }
```

It then runs the function once but does not repeat. I tried running it in both chrome and firefox and got the same result. I am very confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling functions with setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800512/calling-functions-with-settimeout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:-

```
 setInterval(testI, 1000);
```

You have to pass the function reference here. Then setInterval function will invoke it. But right now you are invoking the function here instead of passing reference.

Comment: Oh my god thank you thank you thank you. i feel stupid